# Как после debug-а оставить приложение на телефоне?

Tags: отладка, android, android-studio

Здравствуйте. Работаю в Android Studio 0.8.10. Тестирую на устройстве по USB. Раньше: запускаю приложение, оно устанавливается, создается иконка на рабочем столе и в меню. Через какое-то время можно открыть и пользоваться. Сейчас почему-то иконки не создаются, но в диспетчере приложений оно есть. И получается, что если закрыл приложение, то нужно опять его "открывать", подключая к компу и запуская приложение (опять установка и т.д.).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, куда копать, от чего это зависит?
Спасибо.

Comment: @hailovigor, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Посмотри, есть ли активити с intent-filter для лянчера.

Comment: есть.. может в application в манифесте что-то должно быть для этого?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй врукопашную с командной строки:

```
adb install <path-to-apk>
```

Всяко-разно выдаст диагностику либо в консоли, либо в логах.

Answer (score 0):

Удали приложение с телефона, перезагрузи телефон. Что-то глюкнуло, оно должно корректно устанавливаться.

Возможно, у приложения поменялась цифровая подпись, и оно не может перезаписать то, что в телефоне.

Comment: Не помогло, к сожалению.